# use Bitcoin in Iran

Tags: money, proof-provenance-of-funds, exchange, iran

As Iran's banking system is disconnected from the rest of the world due to sanctions there are limited ways to get Iranian Rial (IRR). The only way I managed to find is to bring foreign currency (EUR/USD) into the country and [exchange](https://ramzinex.com) it.

For obvious reasons I prefer not carrying around large amounts of cash and I was wondering if there are places in bigger cities to exchange Bitcoins for cash (IRR), and if this is possible, what are the exchange rates?

Comment: You might have better results if you post in the Stack Exchange site [specifically directed at Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com).

Comment: How much cash would you like to exchange?

Comment: The Iranian government goes so far as to subsidize Bitcoin miners, so long as they sell the mined currency to the Central Bank...

Answer (score 1):

There are several online crypto markets and exchanges available there.

Also, you definitely can find some local exchanges in major cities that can exchange crypto for you, especially if it's been stable coins like Tether.